# Gráficos bugados com o matplotlib

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para plotar o gráfico.

```
import pandas as pd
HomoCC1 = pd.read_table('CC/Homo CC 1 txt.txt', sep=';').drop(0)
x = HomoCC1.iloc[:, 0].values
y = HomoCC1.iloc[:, 1].values
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title('Homo CC 1')
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=10)
plt.savefig('Homo CC 1.jpeg', format='jpeg')
plt.show();
```

O eixos do gráfico estão saíndo com "rasuras". Segue a imagem e a base de dados no link: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkSWaPHeEDI4wUhJ3Nd63oEnHdJEqSt8/view?usp=sharing, [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMbaklpdtj13Zg0OEcwgQeLtaOvZ389s/view?usp=sharing>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMbaklpdtj13Zg0OEcwgQeLtaOvZ389s/view?usp=sharing%3E)

Answer (score 0):

O motivo do seu gráfico aparecer essas rasuras se deve pelo fato dos valores únicos no seu x e y. Rodei o comando `len(np.unique(x))` e `len(np.unique(y))` para saber a quantidade de valores únicos do seu x e y. Existem `3401` valores únicos no x e `498` no y, com base nisso, quando você for executa o `plt.scatter(x,y)` para aparecer o gráfico de dispersão, o **scatter** vai gerar o gráfico e vai utilizar os valores únicos do x (3401) e do y (498) para formalizar os eixos. Por conta disso apareceu aquela rasura no gráfico, devido a quantidade de valores nos eixos x e y.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Código

Para não aparecer essa grande quantidade de valores nos eixos x e y, vou utilizar o `np.linspace` para pegar os valores mínimos e máximos e quebrar eles em `num` quantidade (na hora que for copiar o código basta mudar o valor do parâmetro `num` para quebrar em quantas quantidades que você deseja), e vou passar esse valor para o `plt.xticks`/`plt.yticks`

Código (**deixei alguns comentários no código para te auxilia**r)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

HomoCC1 = pd.read_table('CC/Homo CC 1 txt.txt', sep=';').drop(0)

# converter os valores de object para float
x = HomoCC1['Criado como novo conjunto de dados'].astype(float)
y = HomoCC1['Unnamed: 1'].astype(float)

# definindo os intervalos, lembrando se você quer quebrar em quantas partes
# os eixos basta informar no num
intervalo_x = np.linspace(x.min(),
                x.max(), num=5)
intervalo_y = np.linspace(y.min(),
                y.max(), num=2)

plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Homo CC 1')
plt.xticks(intervalo_x)
plt.yticks(intervalo_y)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=10)
# plt.savefig('Homo CC 1.jpeg', format='jpeg')
plt.show();
```

Resultado (gráfico com eixos definidos):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]